How to reattach a hinge with very little clearance
I have a window hinge that needs to be reattached, but the side of the building is giving me only about 1 or 1.5” of clearance for the two innermost screws. I can open the window enough to get the two outermost screws beyond the edge of the building facade to screw them in with a standard drill.
What can I do about the innermost screws? Open to creative suggestions as long as hinge is secure. Thanks.



Put "drill" out of your mind as step one, here. Power screwdriver as well.

Casement windows are usually designed to be "easily" removed and replaced. Try locating the appropriate instructions based on the manufacturer of the window.  One example is here.

do not use a power tool to insert screws in the window ... it is too easy to strip the threads

There are screwdrivers that are bent like a hex key/wrench.

There are u-joint drivers.

Just a couple of images found online for examples.

Ratcheting screwdrivers in a right-angle format are also available/common. Standard hex driver bits slot into a hex with ratchet driver in a lever handle, so you only need the length of the driver bit for clearance to get them in.

Even better may be a low profile offset screwdriver for that screw closest to the window frame.  Example: https://www.amazon.com/NEIKO-01323A-Screwdriver-Phillips-Pozidriv/dp/B07GNPRRVZ
